# Is it NSCalendar bug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

**Why are the last two lines of the output the same?**

Use NSCalendar to calculate the diff between startTime and endTime, find that the diff between @"2008-02-28 00:00:00" and @"2022-02-28 00:00:00" and the diff between @"2008-02-29 00:00:00" and @"2022-02-28 00:00:00" are the same. It looks like a bug of NSCalendar, maybe about leapMonth?

*code:*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self printDiffBetweenStartTime:@"2008-02-27 00:00:00" endTime:@"2022-02-28 00:00:00"];
    [self printDiffBetweenStartTime:@"2008-02-28 00:00:00" endTime:@"2022-02-28 00:00:00"];
    [self printDiffBetweenStartTime:@"2008-02-29 00:00:00" endTime:@"2022-02-28 00:00:00"];
}

- (void)printDiffBetweenStartTime:(NSString *)startTime endTime:(NSString *)endTime
{
    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        dateFormatter.calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    });
    
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startTime];
    NSDate *endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endTime];
    
    NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];
    NSLog(@"\"%@\" to \"%@\" : %@ year %@ month %@ day %@ hour %@ minute %@ second", startTime, endTime, @(components.year), @(components.month), @(components.day), @(components.hour), @(components.minute), @(components.second));

}
```

*output:*

```
"2008-02-27 00:00:00" to "2022-02-28 00:00:00" : 14 year 0 month 1 day 0 hour 0 minute 0 second
"2008-02-28 00:00:00" to "2022-02-28 00:00:00" : 14 year 0 month 0 day 0 hour 0 minute 0 second
"2008-02-29 00:00:00" to "2022-02-28 00:00:00" : 14 year 0 month 0 day 0 hour 0 minute 0 second
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. There are many ways to do these period calculations, and the one that `NSCalendar` uses turns out to not be the one you expected.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1407925-components) briefly describes what it does:

> Some operations can be ambiguous, and the behavior of the computation is calendar-specific, but generally larger components will be computed before smaller components; for example, in the Gregorian calendar a result might be 1 month and 5 days instead of, for example, 0 months and 35 days.

What this means is that it will compute how many *years* are in between the two dates first, then months, then days, and so on. "Years" is the biggest component you requested.

And `NSCalendar` finds that adding 14 years to 2008-02-28 makes exactly 2022-02-28. Adding 14 years to 2008-02-29 is also exactly 2022-02-28, because 2022 is not a leap year. Note that "adding a year" does not mean the same as "adding 12 months" or "adding 365 days".

For a difference to appear in this case, you need to compute the days first. One period has 5114 days, and the other has 5113.

A few more examples:

If you instead compute the year, month, day period between 2008-02-28 and 2022-02-01, and the period between 2008-02-29 and 2022-02-01. You wouldn't see a difference, both are 13 years, 11 months, and 4 days. This is because adding 13 years to both 2008-02-29 and 2008-02-28 gets you to 2021-02-28, then adding 11 months is 2022-01-28. 4 days after that is 2022-02-01.

However, if you only compute months and days, the period between 2008-02-28 and 2022-02-01, and the period between 2008-02-29 and 2022-02-01 are different.

The period between 2008-02-28 and 2022-02-01 is 167 months and 4 days. Adding 167 months to 2008-02-28 is 2022-01-28. 4 days after that is 2022-02-01.

The period between 2008-02-29 and 2022-02-01 is 167 months and ***3*** days. Adding 167 months to 2008-02-29 is 2022-01-29. 3 days after that is 2022-02-01.

Period calculations are weird, aren't they! But they are consistent in a unique way.